# Search with accented characters in a mysql JSON data type

Tags: mysql, json, full-text-search

I have a table with a column of type JSON type.
I want to do a text search on this field, but it appears that the search is sensible to accents.

Here are some basics mysql queries:

```
SELECT '["étoile", "foo"]'  LIKE '%etoil%'; -- return 1
SELECT '["étoile", "foo"]'  LIKE '%étoil%'; -- return 1
```

Results are differents with Json type

```
SELECT CAST('["étoile", "foo"]' AS JSON) LIKE '%etoil%'; -- return 0
SELECT CAST('["étoile", "foo"]' AS JSON) LIKE '%étoil%'; -- return 1
```

I also tried using mysql json functions,

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH( CAST('["étoile", "foo"]' AS JSON), 'all', '%etoil%'); -- return NULL
SELECT JSON_SEARCH( CAST('["étoile", "foo"]' AS JSON), 'all', '%étoil%');-- return "$[0]"
```

It is not possible to specify a Charset on a JSON data field.

At this point the solution would be to revert the column From the JSON type to  to a basic text column (still containing JSON but without the mysql validation).

Are there any possibilities to make a query unsensitive to accent in a JSON data type field?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
SELECT
  COLLATION(`json_value`),
  `json_value` LIKE '%etoil%',
  `json_value` LIKE '%etoil%' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  JSON_SEARCH(`json_value`, 'all', '%etoil%'),
  JSON_SEARCH(`json_value`, 'all', '%etoil%' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci)
FROM `tbltest`;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/usUXwexeefxUA2Uic2La1n/0).